# How to diagnose why semantic-imenu does not correctly parse a file?

Tags: helm, semantic-mode

When spelunking through Java code, I rely heavily on the semantic integration through the use of `helm-semantic-or-imenu` to navigate to different functions in a file.

This works great for simple to moderately-complex Java files, however, some complex Java files show an empty semantic imenu. There are no errors in the log, only the customary:

```
Parsing NettyTransport.java (LALR)...done
```

And then the imenu is empty.

How can I diagnose and/or fix the semantic parsing for these Java files so they correctly show functions/vars/etc in the imenu?

For reference, a Java file that silently fails semantic parsing can be found [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/d4d77cdb66e1c23a2639a3fd578a3965fc687172/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/transport/netty/NettyTransport.java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `M-x bovinate` to see what the parser will dump. On the file you linked it's fairly obvious from the output that it gets stuck near the class definition. The offending token is `AbstractLifecycleComponent<Transport>`. You can test this yourself by deleting the "extends" portion of that class definition and trying again.

This is a problem with the parser used in `wisent/java-tags.el` in both the `cedet` included in recent versions of emacs, and in the `cedet` development version. There is an alternative parser that works fine with your example file, and basically everything I've ever thrown at it, included in the development version of `cedet`. Just make sure that the full parser is loaded in favour of the inaccurate but fast `java-tags.el` parser. You can do this by messing with `cedet`'s autoloads using the following:

```
(autoload 'wisent-java-default-setup "semantic/wisent/java")
```

Comment: Is there a package available anywhere (MELPA?) with a development snapshot of CEDET? Or how can I use the development version of CEDET? Just clone the repo and add to the load-path?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure where to make the `autoload` change, should I change the CEDET source to do that? Should it be in my personal configuration before I load semantic-mode?

Comment: @LeeH, unfortunately, the nature of CEDET makes it difficult to use with `package.el`. The main reason for this is that it needs to be able to unload older built in versions of itself before a particular library is loaded (`eieio`), this lib happens to be a dep of `package.el`.

As for the `autoload`, it should come after manually loading the cedet setup files.